# React navigation proper naming

Tags: react-native

What is the proper naming in react native navigation if it's composed of two words. It should have space or no space? Which one below is correct?

```
<Stack.Screen name="User Settings" component={UserSettings} />
<Stack.Screen name="UserSettings" component={UserSettings} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when naming, avoid spacing in between. If the string is going to be visible to the user then add space otherwise userSettings or UserSettings can work. you can also do USER_SETTINGS if constant. In this particular case I would go with userSettings.